# How to use OBEX/Bluecove with Android 

Tags: android

I have an task to share an file over bluetooth by programatically.I tried to use few samples provided from stackoverflow.But it failed to recognize the exact solution.Let me know how to use OBEX api on android.

I tried Bluecove jar implementation with android, I added the jar in build path, when I run the App it shows an error like - `BlueCove native library version mismatch` can you please provide me necessary solution to fix this problem.
when i use loadlibrary, it usually points that
 javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove native library version mismatch.

Help me to fix this issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to use an existing application to send a file via BT (sharing functionality is one of the architectural goals of Android). Install an app (search for bluetooth in the playstore) and use a method similar to the following one to send your file:

```
private File exportFile;  // set when creating the file

/**
 * Send the export file via an intent with the send action.
 */
private void doSendFile() {
    final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(this.exportFile));
    i.setType("text/*");
    final Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(i, this.global.getText(R.string.txt_send_chooser_title));  // R.string.... is the label's ID for the chooser headline
    chooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    this.startActivity(chooser);
}
```

Comment: @Stefan.. I too know the way to share by this method..I would like to share an file natively. Can you provide me an idea to implement he same without using intent.

Comment: No, I don't, because I decided to reuse the existing component instead, which saved a lot of my time.

Comment: I tried to use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179526/access-androids-obex-server-and-read-data